# Twitter Cards - No Meta tags found

Tags: meteor, twitter, kadira

I've added all the pre-req meta tags to the header, but the validator always gives me.

> INFO: Page fetched successfully
>   WARN: No metatags found

Read one post re: adding content type text/html.  Wasn't quite sure how to do that via dochead so I added a whole bunch of attempts to the top.

I'm running React on Meteor with Kadira dochead.

[image: meta header]

Comment: I've also added a robot.txt to the public folder.  And the fact it finds my server leads me to believe its not blocked.

Answer (score 1):

The meta tags are rendered dynamically with JavaScript after the page is loaded, and Twitter (and other social networks, or social engines) don't execute the JavaScript, so they don't see those tags.

You may want to look for meteor's different server-side rendering solutions, like the [spiderable package](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/spiderable).

Comment: Thanks Julien.  w/ 1.3 I think the new way is via prerender.io - but to the exact same effect as spiderable.  (accept now it runs on a 3rd party versus on your own server - which for me means use 3rd party until it becomes more economical to run myself).  Patrick Lewis had a recommendation on another package that renders earlier into the Head that sounded worth trying...

Comment: In my case it works on facebook sharing and doesn't work in twitter. what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue until I added the `Content-Type: text/html` header to the server's response.

In other words, adding meta tags specifying that the content is `text/html` as you have done is not sufficient - the server that serves the web page in question must also provide the `Content-Type: text/html` header.